# SQL AND Clause performance optimisation

Tags: sql, database-performance

Hi I need help in optimizing the blow query

```
SELECT * FROM {SOME TABLE} T <WITH SOME JOIN>
WHERE T.C0 = 0
AND   T.C1 = 0
AND   T.C2 = 0
AND   T.C3 = 0
AND   T.C4 = 0
AND   T.C5 = 0
AND   T.C6 = 0
```

It takes considerably a huge amount of time since I am checking for the values of 6 same data typed columns with `AND` condition.

Comment: What dbms are you using? (`SQL` ins't enough as a tag). You most probably need indexes on all of those 6 columns. But trying to optimize with no information is like driving very fast in a fog. Have you looked at the `explain plan` or `execution plan`? (term depends on database vendor) These are the very first thing to look for when optimizing a query, and something you should provide along with your question. (don't use images of that output).

Comment: If you are very very sure (without examining the execution plan) that performance issues are caused by this concrete clause and this concrete table, then you can add a covering index on `T(c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6)`. But this may not make sense and may even worsen the situation. Please generate the execution plan and append it to the question, this is a first basic step which is a must when trying to optimize the query.

Comment: Apparently, you have some gross misconceptions about performance. If you are genuinely interested in learning about SQL performance, have a look here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents